# Bash get key value Error

Tags: bash

i get from get_key_value this error:

```
get_key_value.c(113) Buffer is too small
```

what does it mean ??
is the value that i will get from a file to big ?
This Message makes me not really clever...

What i do is get the key value from this:

```
only_to_show="webapi_file_SSD2fe; webapi_file_BuEJl3; webapi_file_Cv4RI2; webapi_file_l4oUGQ; webapi_file_Gr1oEz; webapi_file_0d3Dpu"
```

and set an other in it...:

```
only_to_show="webapi_file_SSD2fe; webapi_file_BuEJl3; webapi_file_Cv4RI2; webapi_file_l4oUGQ; webapi_file_Gr1oEz; webapi_file_0d3Dpu; NEW_TO_SHOW_YOE_WHAT_I_MEAN"
```

is there another way maybe with awk or sed ??

i hope everyone understand my Problem

Comment: Isn't this a [tag:C] problem, rather than [tag:bash]? And before you change tags, you might want to add a [mcve].

Comment: No, we don't understand your problem. That doesn't look like a bash error message. What is `get_key_value`? Please post the script that's getting the error.

Comment: sure, get_key_value is a bash tool..... `root@Synology_DS214:~# get_key_value
Usages: get_key_value file key
root@Synology_DS214:~# `this is the Usages of get_key_value